# How to client side authentication with Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

First of all I don't use Ruby nor Devise :) (all my searches led me to plugins that kind of rely on Devise)

I want to do pretty simple authentication with Ember, I have a REST backend that blocks requests without a proper cookie(user-pass) and i want Ember to watch when it gets 403 forbidden (won't let you to transition into protected URLs) and then pop up a user-login dialog.

So when a user tries to send a new message for example(lets say i've built a forum) Ember will fire the request and if it gets 403 it will block the transition and popup a login form and will retry the transition after the login have completed

Also is there a way to get the errors from ember-data and respond to them? (if a user tries to change an attribute he can't access i would like to inform him about it[Access denied or something like that])
I want to use custom errors that my server will send to ember data not just error numbers but words like "Sorry you can't change this before 12 PM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply listen to the response of your server and transition to your LOGIN (or whatever you call it) route. In my apps I happen to keep two types of routes (LOGIN and AUTHENTICATED). When they access the authenticated routes without logging in, they get a 401 unauthorized error and get transitioned to the LOGIN route.

```
// AuthenticatedRoute.js

redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
    // alert('You must log in!');
    var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
    loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
    this.transitionTo('login');
},

events: {
    error: function(reason, transition) {
        if (reason.status === 401) {
            this.redirectToLogin(transition);
        } else {
            console.log(reason);
            window.alert('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
},

model: function () {
    return this.store.find('post'); 
},
```

So now when the user requests for post he gets a 401 and gets transitioned to LOGIN controller.

```
// LoginController.js

login: function() {

var self = this, data = this.getProperties('username', 'password');

// Clear out any error messages.
this.set('errorMessage', null);

$.post('/login', data).then(function(response) {

  self.set('errorMessage', response.message);
  if (response.success) {
    alert('Login succeeded!');

    // Redirecting to the actual route the user tried to access
    var attemptedTransition = self.get('attemptedTransition');
    if (attemptedTransition) {
      attemptedTransition.retry();
      self.set('attemptedTransition', null);
    } else {
      // Redirect to 'defaultRoute' by default.
      self.transitionToRoute('defaultRoute');
    }
  }
});
```

}

The basic answer you need is capturing the events in the route and transitioning accordingly. I just happened to include the code for attempted transition as it comes in handy at times.